regularity convolution of a $L^2$ function with $W^{1,1}$ function
Let $u\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $w \in W^{1,1}(\mathbb R)$, we consider the convolution
$$u*v$$
Is it true that $w*u \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb R)$?
What regularity can we put on $w$ for this to be true?

Sure, $(uw)' = uw'$, and use Young's convolution inequality, but I don't think this is a good question for MathOverflow.
